# Python. How can I remove a specific key in an array?

Tags: python, arrays, key

I have the code:

```
a = {"listA" : ("keyA", "keyB"), "listB" : ("keyC", "keyD")}
```

How can I for example remove the KeyB so:

```
a = {"listA" : ("keyA"), "listB" : ("keyC", "keyD")}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a dict not a list with tuples as values, you would need to reassign the value as tuples are [immutable](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html) so you cannot remove an element:

```
a = {"listA" : ("keyA", "keyB"), "listB" : ("keyC", "keyD")}

a["listA"] =  a["listA"][0],
print(a)
```

If you want to be able to modify the values use lists as values which are mutable:

```
a = {"listA" : ["keyA", "keyB"], "listB" : ["keyC", "keyD"]}

a["listA"].remove("keyB")

print(a)
```

Comment: Thank you, that was quite informing!

Comment: @GeorgeTsak, no worries, if you control how the dict is created and want to be able to modify the values easily use a list.